# how to reach amount of entropy of image in between the range [0,1] in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, entropy

Usually the amount of entropy is between the range [0,1]. but after run

```
 E = entropy(I)
```

E is a scalar value representing the entropy of grayscale image I that E>1.i want E between [0,1]. please guide me or suggest an another function.

Comment: _Usually the amount of entropy is between the range [0,1]_ No it's not. See the definition of entropy. You say you want another function between 0 and 1, but with only that information we can't suggest anything

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the output by the maximum entropy for this image.

```
 H = entropy(I);
 N = numel(I);
 maxH = entropy([1:N]/N);
 Hscaled = H/maxH;
```

Answer courtesy: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/293322-how-to-reach-amount-of-entropy-of-image-in-between-the-range-0-1